# Availability of Apex data loader error file from local PC to salesforce

Tags: apex

I am new to salesforce and want to do following task.

Basically using salesforce dataloader when dataload fails it creates an error file with error details. But since dataloader tool is a client tool so, error file is there on the file system where dataloader tool is installed. Can we look out for the possible ways where we can make this error file available somewhere (may be as a document in some folder or as an alert task) online in the org where user can download or view the error details? And if we are able to email these error files to the user from the org.

If it is good to use trigger or any other technique.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be specify on automation of this ?You will need to develop this functionality itself then using partner or enterprise WSDL

Comment: As I am new to this can you please suggest me the best way to implement this..
Thanks.

Comment: I think your question might be too broad. You will need to break this down into steps. Are you initiating this Dataloader run by an automation? How will your automation detect failure and then move information about the failure onto Salesforce. There are a number of APIs that you can use to move data, but this will require client side coding. If there are large volumes of (potential) failed data this may change your approach. Where in Salesforce are you going to store the failure information (a custom object?) and then what kind of notification do your users require?

Comment: HI Doug B, for automatic data loader run May be we override default dataloader main around a wrapper bean  And in that wrapper bean we detect the failure of the load run. In salesforce  May be we use existing document object or even custom object if we are able to store full file as blob content.

Answer (score 1):

The data loader does not have this functionality by default, and the salesforce.com platform doesn't have a mechanism that supports recording failed transactions reliably. As such, you have two basic choices: (a) you can write a "shell script" to upload the files to salesforce.com using the data loader when the error file isn't empty, or (2) you could modify the data loader from [forcedotcom/dataloader](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader), and add this functionality in yourself. Either way, some client-side programming experience would be required (most likely Java).